# Google maps передача массива из php в js

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Привет всем подскажите пожалуйста как реализуется передача json массива из php в javascript?

я придумал несколько вариантов:
1. создать какой-то елемент хайден и в него записать весь json
2. через Ajax обратится к php  и запросить json
3. через php создать файл "array.json" и к нему обращаться за массивом

Какой лучше выбирать?  или может есть какой то лучше путь?
Спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я считаю 1 и 2 самые оптимальные - если данные могут изменяться, 3 - если данных очень много и они не меняются. С точки зрения загрузки страницы (не требуется делать дополнительный http запрос) в приоритете 1 вариант.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если хочешь, чтоб данные оказались на клиенте сразу после загрузки страницы лучше бутстрапить данные (твой вариант с элементом hidden) лучше завернуть это в элемент `<script>` и в какой-нибудь объект в качестве неймспейса https://github.com/gazay/gon тут можно почитать как это делается для Ruby он Rails (для php не знаю к сожалению подобных решений). Таким образом ты экономишь один ajax запрос.

Если тебе во время работы на клиенте нужны данные лучше делать с помощью ajax запроса иначе можно сказать никак.

А по поводу файла, тут наверное имеет смысл скинуть массив в файл только если он статический хотя такой случай маловероятен.